# Did anyone successfully implemented Gödel machine? Is it practically possible to implement?

Tags: machine-learning

For reference - Gödel machine is a hypothetical self-improving computer program that solves problems. It uses a recursive self-improvement protocol in which it rewrites its own code when it can prove the new code provides a better strategy. So let's say you have a program which solves TSP using Simulated Annealing, you leave it running through the night and in the morning it rewrote itself so now it uses Genetic Algorithm. A self modifying code. Did anyone ever implemented something like that? According to linked book I found there are some implementations but I've never seen any project actually working. If any actual implementation doesn't exist is it possible to implement it in practice?

Link: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22887-2_29

Comment: The closest thing is probably AI writing code.  Anything interesting would require waiting a few decades if not a century or two.  http://news.mit.edu/2019/toward-artificial-intelligence-that-learns-to-write-code-0614